# Miro Guide or Ubuntu music store wouldnt open in Banshee

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one, banshee, rhythmbox, miro

I am using ubuntu 12.04, I recently updated from the 11.10 version.

The Miro guide or the Ubuntu music store wouldnt open in Banshee or Rhythmbox music player.
it always leaves the following message:

```
Unable to load page
Problem occurred while loading the URL http://integrated-services.banshee.fm/miro/audio/home/
Cannot resolve proxy hostname ()
```

Comment: Do you have a network proxy configured (see `Network` under `System Settings`)?  If so, is it possible that there is a problem with the proxy configuration?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Ubuntu One music store for Banshee in Ubuntu 12.04.

As for the proxy hostname error, your proxy configuration is broken. You need to fix it by opening `System Settings`, going to `Network`, selecting the `Network proxy` item in the list, and either disabling or fixing the proxy.

If it is set to none, you can open the `Terminal` application, and run `gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.system.proxy` to reset the configuration back to the default of having no proxy.